# Here API returns Unrecognized Kid Null error

Tags: rest, curl, here-api, here-maps-rest

This is my cURL request

```
curl https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=5%20Rue%20Daunou%2C%2075000%20Paris%2C%20France -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

This is the response

```
{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"Token Validation Failure - unrecognized kid null"}
```

I am not sure what is going on. I tried different access keys. I generated new ones. But keep getting the same error.

Comment: what api is it?

Comment: @Yadu its a rest API.

Comment: please drop the documentation

Comment: Are you sure your token is right? If I make the same call but with my apikey in the URL, it works fine.

Answer (score 9):

The "Access Key ID" is not quite the token you need to send in the *Authorization* header, which is why you get a ***"Token Validation Failure"***.

The "Access Key ID" is however one of the credential parameter that you need, in order to generate the OAuth tokens, the other parameter being the "Access Key Secret".

If you didn't save the Access Key Secret already, go to your [HERE Account Project Management Space](https://developer.here.com/projects) and make sure to download the credential file:

[image]
[image]

In the credential file, pay attention to the last three lines:

```bash
here.access.key.id = redacted
here.access.key.secret = redacted_redacted_redacted
here.token.endpoint.url = https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token
```

**Then, we can use Postman to generate the OAuth tokens:**

- Open Postman and create a new request.
- Method POST, url: https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token
- Go to the *Auth* tab and select:

  - Type: OAuth 1.0
  - Add auth data to Request Headers (probably the default choice)
  - Signature Method: HMAC-SHA256
  - Consumer Key: put the `here.access.key.id` value
  - Consumer Secret: put the `here.access.key.secret` value
- Go to the *Body* tab and select:

  - `x-www-form-urlencoded`
  - Key: `grant_type`, Value: `client_credentials`
- Send the request. You should receive an access token. That one should work with your curl request.

**Auth tab**

[image]

**Body tab**

[image]

#### Note

For the record, the following, not using OAuth but an "API key" to be found under the REST section as well, also works:

```sh
curl https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=<REST-API-KEY>&q=5%20Rue%20Daunou%2C%2075000%20Paris%2C%20France
```

However the [Geocode API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html) does not document the *apiKey* authentication, unlike other HERE API e.g. [Routing](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.7.1/api-reference-swagger.html), and I would not recommend it besides for occasional experiments with curl requests.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution. I removed the Authorization header and added the "apiKey" query parameter to my URL.

For example:

```
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?48.2181679%2C16.3899064&lang=en-US&apiKey={TOKEN}
```